# how to change value of a field before updating database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

First let's  go through my codes. Here is my CONTROLLER part:

```
 public function store(Request $request){

        $data=$request->all();
        $adminProfile=AdminProfile::find(1);

        $image = $request->file('admin_propic')->getClientOriginalName();
        $gallery = new AdminProfile();
        $gallery->admin_propic= $image;
        $adminProfile->admin_propic=$image;
        $request->admin_propic->move(public_path('uploaded'),$image);

        $request->admin_propic = $image;
        if($adminProfile){
            $adminProfile->update($request->all());
        }
        else{
            AdminProfile::create($data);
        }

         return view('dashboard part-admin.edit_profile');
    }
```

now, the thing is, when I am updating profile picture (admin_propic), it's setting the path of temporary picture instead of it's original name. But, in my "uploaded" folder, the profile picture is being uploaded at it's real name. So, I tried to change it's value from the controller part. But it's not working.

** $image contains the desired value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
public function store(Request $request){

        $data=$request->all();
        $adminProfile=AdminProfile::find(1);

        $image = $request->file('admin_propic')->getClientOriginalName();
        $gallery = new AdminProfile();
        $gallery->admin_propic= $image;
        $adminProfile->admin_propic=$image; 
        $request->admin_propic->move(public_path('uploaded'),$image);

       // $request->admin_propic = $image;  this will not work i think as request object is readonly as far as i know.
        if($adminProfile){ 
            // updated here 
            $data['admin_propic'] = $image
            $adminProfile->update($data);
        }
        else{
            AdminProfile::create($data);
        }

         return view('dashboard part-admin.edit_profile');
    }
```